# Which SSO tool fits this scenario best?

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, saml

ClientSiteA.com, ClientSiteB.com, ....

(client domains are unknown to us)

OurServer.com
(contains all the user credentials)

We need users to be able to login on OurServer.com (using JavaScript) on any client site. The login form must reside on client sites. So I am envisioning an ajax call sent to OurServer.com containing username (from any client site). If the username is logged in, let them do stuff, if not show them a login form. This login form will send their username/password to the server and log them in.

Is this possible? I've been reading about SAML, but I'm seeing having the login form on the client sites could be a problem. I've also been reading about oAuth. I'm pretty lost. Can anyone give me some guidance.

Comment: What is the reason for the login form to be physically situated at the client site?

Comment: The reason is to make the login process easier. I could do an iframe or something I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is easier to have the same UI repeated over multiple sites, this makes maintenance much more difficult.

On the other hand, if there is an explicit link for users to login or they are automatically redirected when accessing restricted sites then there is NO need for this awkward requirement. Awkward - because it makes it tricky to use existing sso protocols.

Answering your question - OAuth2 lets you exchange username/passwords for access tokens. It is called the **Resource Owner Password Credential** flow.

Trying to convince you that this is not a good idea - not all OAuth2 providers support this flow, from what I remember Google doesn't. Instead, they support flows which redirect client to their login page where they can perform just anything your client application is not aware of like:

- multifactor authentication
- additional confirmation pages for explicit resource access approval

These additional steps of authentication are just not possible in the simple username/password flow.

Comment: The reason the same UI is repeated is because I am distributing software for people to install on their websites.

Comment: You don't have to, they can redirect to your site. Anyway, if you still insist, the OAuth2 Resource Owner is probably a way to go for you.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "redirect"? I'm open to different workflows. I just want this to be the best possible user experience.

Comment: Just an anchor, "Login" which points to your SSO gateway. Try to sign in to Stackoverflow using Google/Facebook whatever they support. The SO doesn't make you provide your Google credentials on their SO site. Instead, you are redirected to Google, the identity provider. This is how SSO protocols work. Do you have any background on existing SSO protocols? OAuth2, WS-Federation?

Comment: I don't have a background. I've messed with SAML stuff before. The login is part of a commenting service. I want people to be able to login to the commenting service as they post the comment. I feel like a redirect would be disruptive. What do you think?

Comment: It won't be. People login with google/facebook/live accounts using redirects/popup windows, you really don't need the ui to be a part of the service's website. I really recommend reading oauth2/ws-federation (saml) tutorials and you can come back with more questions on specific issues.

Comment: Wiktor, what flow would you recommend. I'm fine with doing it how Facebook does it - login popup.

Comment: I have never tried the "popup login window" approach myself, however, I am 100% sure this is possible. Instead, we always redirect users to the login page so that the flow follows WS-Federation/OAuth2 conventions. These two protocols differ slightly in details and ask questions if you need further assistance. I think that could be handy too http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28362

Comment: Although the book describes the WS-Federation made with Microsoft's WIF library, just read few initial chapters to get the idea on how SSO protocols work. You don't have to use this particular implementation. I have found this book to be really clear and understandable.

Comment: The problem with the pop-up window approach is that users have to give their credentials to site A to site B.  Which is a big security hole if site B isn't owned and controlled by Site A.  Users should only give their credentials to the site that is authenticating them to prevent them being compromised.  SAML was designed with that in mind.